# Is there any function to convert a python code to MIPS?

Tags: python, assembly, mips

I tried

```
import dis

dis.dis(myfunc)
```

But still not getting the MIPS

Answer (score 0):

CPython outputs bytecode, not machinecode, the `dis` module simply allows you to disassemble said bytecode. It does not provide disassemblies for machinecode. There is no built in facility in CPython to convert Python to MIPS but if you want to compile Python to machine code you might want to look at https://cython.org/